# vi doesn't see a file on an over-mounted file system, while ls does

Tags: filesystems, mount, vi

I have been editing and trouble shooting a script.  When I tried to edit it now, it shows an empty file and says[New File].  The file exists both ls and cat see it.  And, I had edited about 10 minutes before. It doesn't appear to be a permission problem since I am logged in as root.  Both vi and vim are acting the same way.

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 3.2K Oct 20 10:30 CreateNgsIso.sh*
```

UPDATE:

I figured out the problem.  My script inadvertently deleted all the files in the directory.  I am doing this remotely via ssh.  In all the established ssh sessions, 'ls', 'cat', and 'scp' see the original files.  If I initate another ssh session, I see the new files installed by the script and none of the old files.  The new question is why does the established ssh sessions see the old files while the new session sees the new files.

Comment: This is the output of `ls CreateNgsIso.sh`? And if you replace the `ls` with `vi`, it's not found? How about if you replace it with `cat`?

Comment: "_why do the established ssh sessions see the old files while the new session sees the new files_" - different directory? different host?

Comment: @roaima same host, same directory.  I sshed into the server, changed to the directory, and ran the script.  'ls' saw the orignal files.  I started a second ssh session same host, same directory.  This session saw the new files; but, not the old ones.  However, the first session was still seeing the old files while not seeing the new ones.

Comment: As in « _session 1_: create files, run the script , run `ls` and still see all the files. Then _session 2_: run `ls` and see no files »?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @roaima, I solved it while trying to solve [related problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674074/can-not-delete-files).

- I created a directory (NGS) and put some files there.
- I ran the script which inadverently mounted a DVD to the NGS directory.
- established ssh sessions saw the original directory's contents (not sure why vi didn't).
- new ssh sessions saw the DVD's contents.

'umount NGS' solved the problem.  The DVD's contents were gone while new ssh sessions could see the original files.