# Can not delete files

Tags: linux, filesystems, rm, readonly

I copied some files from a DVD using the 'cp -a' command.  Now, I can't delete any of the copied files.  I set selinux to "permissive" to remove that as source of the problem.  Here is what I have tried so far:

```
root@zeus:/NGS# getenforce
Permissive
root@zeus:/NGS# rm TRANS.TBL 
rm: remove regular file 'TRANS.TBL'? y
rm: cannot remove 'TRANS.TBL': Read-only file system
root@zeus:/NGS# chmod 755 TRANS.TBL 
chmod: changing permissions of 'TRANS.TBL': Read-only file system
root@zeus:/NGS# lsattr TRANS.TBL 
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on TRANS.TBL
root@zeus:/NGS# ls -lZ TRANS.TBL 
-r--r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:iso9660_t:s0   TRANS.TBL
root@zeus:/NGS# chcon unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0
root@zeus:/NGS# chcon unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 TRANS.TBL 
chcon: failed to change context of 'TRANS.TBL' to 'unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0': Read-only file system
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: The file-system says it's RO. i would check if that's the case with `mount`.

Comment: Read the error messages - it's complaining about a `Read-only file system`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the error you're being given:

> ```
> Read-only file system
> ```

The filesystem is read-only and you will not be able to make any changes to it. It's nothing to do with SELinux or per-file permissions. The entire filesystem is read-only.

If I had to guess I would say that `/NGS` is your DVD's filesystem. You can confirm this with something like `df -h .`, which will point to the device from which the filesystem has been mounted

Comment: That was the problem!  I created NGS as a normal directory with some files in it.  The script was supposed to copy files to a subdirectory.  It somehow mounted the DVD iso to the NGS directory which caused it to act flaky.  Old ssh sessions would see the original files while a new ssh session saw only the DVD's files.  Thanks